# How To Post Data From An Android App To a Website

Tags: java, php, android, android-intent

hi i have developed a app to post data from android to website. now when i run app i got message Unfortunately app has stopped an then ap closed. what is the issue.??

if you have some better idea or tutorial for this purpose please share that also

java code

```
package com.latlongapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button sendButton;

EditText msgTextField;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // make message text field object
    msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
    // make send button object
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
}

 public void send(View v)
    {
        // get the message from the message text box
        String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

        // make sure the fields are not empty
        if (msg.length()>0)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://http://tayyab001.base.pk/kami.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
        else
        {
            // display message if text fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

XML

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="Message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        /> 

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msgTextField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="send"
        /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest

> ```
>     <uses-sdk
>         android:minSdkVersion="8"
>         android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
>
>
>         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
>
>
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>         <activity
>             android:name="com.latlongapp.MainActivity"
>             android:label="@string/app_name" >
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

LOGCAT

```
07-15 08:14:25.184: D/gralloc_goldfish(1108): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-15 08:14:38.134: D/dalvikvm(1108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 8% free 3119K/3360K, paused 40ms, total 42ms
07-15 08:14:38.274: D/AndroidRuntime(1108): Shutting down VM
07-15 08:14:38.274: W/dalvikvm(1108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a5ab90)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Process: com.latlongapp, PID: 1108
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.latlongapp.MainActivity.send(MainActivity.java:54)
07-15 08:14:38.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 14 more
07-15 08:14:43.674: I/Process(1108): Sending signal. PID: 1108 SIG: 9
```

PHP SCript being used is

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$message=$_POST["message"]; 
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` Did you google search with keyword `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i did but not getting exactly what to do?

Comment: @user2590541 do you network operation using a thread asynctask or volley or use retrofit. cannot do network peration on the ui thread

Comment: thanks for quick response but @Raghunandan i m not getting you. please tell me in simple what should i do to overcome this issue.

Comment: Do http post in asynctask

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException is related to, you are trying to perform internet related activity on your main thread. But according to android, if you stop main thread for more than 5 seconds, your will get crashed. So it is always recommended that whenever you perform network related operation try to do those on seperate thread & best way of doing this is use AsyncTask. See these links : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html & http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html